# How to create new data with relation in nodejs using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to create User and profile in the same time. This is my user controller

```
 const create = async (req, res) => {
    var data = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName
    };
    const { username, password, firstName, lastName } = data;

    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, password) {
        findOrCreate({ username, password }, userRepository)
            .then( async (result) => {
                var userId = result[0].id;
                if(firstName && lastName) {
                    await profileCreate({ firstName, lastName, user_id: userId}, profileRepostiory);
                }else{
                    return console.log();;
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                errorMessage = err.errors
                return res.json(errorMessage);
            });
    });
}
```

This is my use case for profile and user

```
module.exports = function findOrCreate(payload, profileRepository){
    return profileRepository.findOrCreate(payload);
};

module.exports = function findOrCreate(payload, userRepository){
   return userRepository.findOrCreate(payload);
};
```

When i try to console log in repository, I didn't get anything feedback when running on it. Did anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need to create the `findOrCreate` methods if you can directly call them using the repos instances.

Try with this code and see if you get any error message:

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, async function (err, password) {
    if (err) return res.send('Error hashing password')
    try {
      const result = await userRepository.findOrCreate({ username, password });
      if (!result || !result.length) return res.send('Error creating user');
      var userId = result[0].id;
      if (firstName && lastName) {
        await profileRepostiory.findOrCreate({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          user_id: userId,
        });
       return res.send('Request has been succeeded'); // if this line is missing, then it will not return the success result.
      } else {
        return res.send('No first name or last name');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      errorMessage = err.errors;
      return res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  });
};
```